# Проблемы с SQL - не та кодировка

Tags: php, sql, кодировка

Делаю SQL-запрос, проблемы с кодировкой.

```
$s = "SELECT SUM( `square` ) 
      FROM `reports`
      WHERE `username` = '$arr[$i]';"
```

Запрос не работает. База в utf-8, скрипт в win-1251.

phpMyAdmin понимает только когда так

```
SELECT SUM( `square` ) 
FROM `reports` 
WHERE `username` = 'Eaai'
```

Как сделать это в скрипте?

Comment: @Анна, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

А установка кодировки запроса не поможет?

```
query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

Comment: нет,не помогло..

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "SELECT SUM(`square`)  FROM `reports` WHERE `username` = '".$arr[$i]."';"
```

Comment: запрос уходит в таком виде SELECT SUM(`square`) FROM `reports` WHERE `username` = 'Иван'
phpAdmin понимает только когда так SELECT SUM( square ) FROM reports WHERE username = 'Eaai'

((